# Can a GNU Make parallel job know which parallel job slot it is running under? (i.e. for -j 50, an index in the range 0..49)

Tags: windows, parallel-processing, gnu-make, legacy

I am trying to use GNU make to run some old code in parallel (say, 50 or 100 instances at a time); but because of a legacy resource issue (*sigh*), each parallel instance has to execute in a separate directory.

Hence I would like to use -j 50 but where:

- job #0 runs in directory0
- job #1 runs in directory1
- job #2 runs in directory2, etc

I can see horrible ways of achieving this (I'm running under Windows 10), but no good way. :-(

Does GNU make offer any mechanism a given parallel job can use to determine the index of the job slot it is running in?

Comment: Maybe use **GNU Parallel** instead, which gives you that feature as `{#}`.

Comment: Maybe you could post some Makefile illustrating what you are trying to achieve. One thing I can think of is to use job's name as part of output directory to make it distinguishable, but of course it all depends on how exactly your Makefiles are built.

Comment: Sadly, none of the approaches suggested here solved the problem as described: GNU Parallel's clever tricks don't quite mesh with GNU make's clever tricks, and I genuinely want to run all the tasks as a variable make, all or some of which might need to be triggered.  So, to get around the problem I've instead written a Windows batch script, which - though somewhat clunky - seems to be doing the right kind of thing when triggered by GNU make.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it in **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel 'cd subdir{} && make' ::: {1..50}
```

If you want to see what it would do, without actually doing anything, add the `--dry-run` option:

```
parallel --dry-run 'cd subdir{} && make' ::: {1..10}
```

**Sample Output**

```
cd subdir1 && make
cd subdir2 && make
cd subdir3 && make
cd subdir4 && make
cd subdir5 && make
cd subdir6 && make
cd subdir7 && make
cd subdir8 && make
cd subdir9 && make
cd subdir10 && make
```

Or, if you want to specify the subdirectories as parameters:

```
parallel 'cd {} && make' ::: subdir*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably fake it easily with a wrapper makefile.

Let's say you want to run a makefile (`Make.slow` say) thousand times, each time with a different parameter, and each time in a different folder.

```
jobs := $(shell seq 1 1000)

.PHONY: all
all: ${jobs} ; : $@ Success

.PHONY: ${jobs}
${jobs}:
    mkdir -p _$@
    ${MAKE} -C _$@ -f ../Make.slow jobno=$@
```

If you have 48 CPUs

```
$ make -j49 all
```

You will end up with 1,000 folders `_1`, `_2` … `_1000`. In each, `Make.old` would have been run with *jobno* set to the number encoded in the folder name.